# How to get daily values in a longer timeframe in google's "Data Commons" API

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i am trying to gather weather data using Data Commons over a large period of time ie. 5years or more but I am not able to get daily data for more then 15 days

if I specify a observation period data changes from daily to yearly which is not useful for me

i am trying to gather weather data using Data Commons 'datacommons_pandas' API function

documentation - https://docs.datacommons.org/api/pandas/

```
#import
import datacommons_pandas

#find a observation
find = datacommons_pandas.build_time_series("country/IND", "Max_Temperature",observation_period="P1Y")

#arrange the find
find.sort_index(ascending=False)
```

[which is giving me (IT'S IN YEARS NOT DAYS)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lcvc.png)

```
#output

2005    47.868370
2004    50.373222
2003    49.637718
2002    51.213158
2001    51.481163
2000    47.351555
1999    49.664116
1998    50.291618
1997    47.235344
1996    47.096397
1995    46.986320
1994    46.475273
1993    47.077599
1992    47.977654
1991    51.113426
1990    48.744408
1989    46.224480
1988    45.879692
1987    48.174461
1986    45.923912
1985    48.515190
1984    47.231743
1983    46.510826
1982    47.208397
1981    46.565453
1980    46.735435
1979    47.426872
1978    47.059013
1977    46.076927
1976    49.218895
1975    45.900780
1974    47.738823
1973    47.230431
1972    46.108421
1971    44.908806
1970    47.381157
1969    47.162926
1968    50.151329
1967    44.285912
1966    46.990807
1965    50.973961
1964    44.635887
1963    46.067314
1962    45.964256
1961    45.974663
1960    47.171288
1959    50.324059
1958    46.324547
1957    45.751274
1956    45.742424
1955    44.885246
1954    47.389763
1953    45.847954
1952    46.351433
1951    46.008202
1950    46.813011
1949    33.175804
dtype: float64
```

**but if I remove the observation period I am getting daily data**

```
#find a observation
find = datacommons_pandas.build_time_series("country/IND", "Max_Temperature")

#arrange the find
find.sort_index(ascending=False)
```

[which is giving me daily values for last 15 days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJuNq.png)

```
#output

2024-03-28    41.1648
2024-03-27    42.3951
2024-03-26    42.1500
2024-03-25    40.4984
2024-03-24    40.7307
2024-03-23    40.3843
2024-03-22    40.4500
2024-03-21    40.1500
2024-03-20    39.6018
2024-03-19    40.9203
2024-03-18    40.2304
2024-03-17    40.5508
2024-03-16    40.0816
2024-03-15    38.8585
2024-03-14    39.8500
2024-03-13    39.9559
dtype: float64
```

**all I want to do is get daily values in a larger time frame like 5 years or so . please help me**